# Gitlab pulling image using dependency proxy

Tags: .net, gitlab

How to pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest images using the dependency proxy in the gitlab it gives 404 error?
When pulling it says 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GitLab Dependancy Proxy with a generic container registry (like `mcr.microsoft.com`) doesn't seem to be supported with GitLab just yet.

I found this epic: https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/6061 so I believe they are going to eventually implement it, but as it is still open, the feature shouldn't be working yet.

Comment: If their images didn’t start with mcr.microsoft.com do you think it would work because I think throes images are still on Dockerhub